# AWS Lambda NodeJs unable to return response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement a simple Node Js example on AWS Lambda,
The code has a sample example of Async library.
The code works fine, but from some reason the Lambda Function return null response.
I am new to Node as well, please help.

**Following is the code -**

```
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            console.log("ONE");
            callback(null, 1);
        },
        function(resp, callback) {
            console.log("TWO : ", resp);
            callback(null, 2);
        },
        function(resp, callback){
            console.log("THREE : ", resp);
            callback(null, "Done");
        }
    ],
    function(err, resp) {
        let response = {};
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error",err);
            response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify('Error!'),
            };
            return response;
        } else {
            console.log("Success",resp);
            response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify('Ok!'),
            };
            return response;
        }
    });
};
```

**Following are the CloudWatch logs -**

```
START RequestId: ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861 Version: $LATEST
2019-03-21T15:15:26.597Z    ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861    ONE
2019-03-21T15:15:26.597Z    ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861    TWO :  1
2019-03-21T15:15:26.597Z    ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861    THREE :  2
2019-03-21T15:15:26.597Z    ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861    Success Done
END RequestId: ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861
REPORT RequestId: ab9aa426-dfc9-44ac-8d96-a4f102e30861  Duration: 37.28 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB
```

**I used the sample Node blueprint, which works fine -**

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: How are you invoking the lambda?

Comment: using the test option from console

Comment: Wouldn't there be a conflict here with `async` from the library async.js and native async?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje When you invoke it from the console, what invocation type are you using? Event? RequestResponse?

Comment: I used the default params but, my code doesn't process them, just does a simple async lib use and should return the "response" object

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky should I remove async from the handler? New to using Node on Lambda :/

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje if you invoke the lambda as an event, it won't return anything, even if there is a return from the function body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the `async` from the handler and use `callback` instead of return:

```
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            console.log("ONE");
            callback(null, 1);
        },
        function(resp, callback) {
            console.log("TWO : ", resp);
            callback(null, 2);
        },
        function(resp, callback){
            console.log("THREE : ", resp);
            callback(null, "Done");
        }
    ],
    function(err, resp) {
        let response = {};
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error",err);
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: 'Error!',
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Success",resp);
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: 'Ok!',
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you're already using Node 8, you don't need to use the outdated, confusing `callback` approach anymore. Use `await` instead

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        await somePromise1 
        await somePromise2
        await somePromise3 
        console.log("Success", resp);
        response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Ok!'),
        };
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
        response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify(err),
        };
        return response;
    }
};
```

where somePromise1, somePromise2 and somePromise3 are your promisified callbacks.

More on async/await [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Comment: But `Promise.all` launches all the Promises in parallel (I believe), while `async.waterfall` launches each Promise after the other, passing the result to the next. But I agree `async/await` is the way to go now, compared to a library like async.js (which, despite the name, is completely different!)

Comment: I initially had this post as `await promise1` `await promise2` and `await promise3` because I thought waterfall was running them sequentially. Then I was like: "Nah, this must be in parallel", so I changed to Promise.all. Then you dropped this comment and I checked the docs and you're right, it's sequential, so I am changing it back to three `await`s instead. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! :)